# ExoPlayer - Unable to play the live stream one after another.

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, exoplayer

I'm using exoplayer for streaming hls live video. The live streaming API url expires every 10 minutes;  so i will stop the player and calls API in every 10 minutes to get the next stream url to play. The exo player is not playing the latest fetched url. Some one pls help me to fix this. I have used the following code to restart it again

```
player.prepare();
player.stop();
player.seekTo(0L);
player.prepare();
player = new DemoPlayer(getRendererBuilder());
```

Comment: Hi Jerin, you just try with native player. It will work as you  expect..

Comment: hls streaming isn't possible in native player.Its only support rtsp.

Comment: you should releasePlayer and prepare again

Comment: I have already tried it.

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: and you need to call setPlayWhenReady to play it

Comment: public void preparePlayer() {
        if (mExoPlayer == null) {
            mExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT, MIN_BUFFER_MS, MIN_REBUFFER_MS);
            mPlayerController = new PlayerControl(mExoPlayer);
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            mExoPlayer.addListener(this);
            mBuilder.build(getContext(), this, mUrl);
        }
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126624/discussion-between-jerin-raj-and-abhishesh).